# Where to find answers to SEO questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation, google, seo

I'm assuming that straight SEO questions are unwanted here.

The question [Good programming website like SO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387797/good-programming-website-like-so) on Stack Overflow provides a good overview of alternative forums but makes no mention of SEO in its nine answers.

The question [Where can I ask questions that aren’t programming questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)? on Meta
mentions ten categories, the closest match for SEO being **Web Design/Hosting/CMS** but that suggests **doctype** as its top suggestion. While **doctype** seems like an excellent resource in some respects (CSS questions for example) it only has 14 questions tagged SEO. Those 14 questions do look good, but if you've become used to the hugely well-populated resource that is Stack Overflow, 14 questions is shockingly small.

The question [Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32545/which-seo-questions-should-be-closed-as-non-programming-non-admin) on Meta doesn't really have much discussion.

So if you've got a tricky SEO question, where do you go? Who do you find yourself asking?

You would think SEO would be a great topic for Q&A along the lines of Stack Overflow, since it's a topic for which there are, intentionally, few hard and fast rules and a lot of conjecture. I'm not looking for rough set of guidelines (sure, they exist), but a good Q&A resource.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: @fretje yeah but I mention 8401 in my post. no mention of SEO over there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can now use the new "Pro Webmasters" stack exchange site, which covers most areas of web site development/maintenance, apart from programming/server admin which are covered by SO/SF.

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is worth adding that this site has an [seo tag](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/seo/info), which currently contains about 24% of the questions on the site. This fits the bill.

Answer (score 4):

At this current time none of the stackoverflow and associate sites provide adequate space to discuss and learn about SEO.

The forums given by Albert are good and if you are serious about learning SEO I recommend SEOmoz.org of which site I am a Pro member. They provide good training for their members and on their free sections. (I do not benefit from this recommendation in any way whatsoever.)